# Unexpected characters in Arduino serial communications

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

I have unexpected characters showing up in my communications between my arduino uno and my PC (Windows).

For this code the arduino is connected to my PC using an RS-232 cable and RS-232 to TTL adapter. So SIM900 in the arduino code here just means the serial connection to my windows PC running python.For this case, what I do is to run the python code which sends the data to the arduino and the arduino recieves and just sends the data back in the `if(SIM900.available())` code block.

Even with the serial encoding as Ascii simply sending the data back from the arduino still gives me this error and I do not know where the non-ascii characters are coming from since both the arduino code and the python code use ascii:

Python code:

```py
    import serial
    import time
    
    port = 'COM3'  # Replace with the appropriate serial port
    baud_rate = 9600
    
    try:
        with serial.Serial(port, baud_rate, timeout=1) as ser:
            data = 'TEST as you go test and test again\r\n'
            encoded_data = data.encode('ascii')  # Replace 'encoding_name' with the desired encoding
            ser.write(encoded_data)
            # ser.write(b'TEST as you go test and test again\r\n')
            # ser.reset_input_buffer()
            time.sleep(1)
            response = ser.read_all()
            response = response.decode('ascii')  # Decode using 'latin1' encoding
            print("Response:", response)
    
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print("Error opening serial port:", e)
```

Arduino code:

```cpp
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    
    SoftwareSerial SIM900(2, 3);
    
    void setup() {
      SIM900.begin(9600);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Enter command");
    }
    
    void loop() {
      if (Serial.available()) {
        String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println("C: " + command);
        sendCommand(command);
      }
    
      // Check if a complete line of response is available
      if (SIM900.available()) {
        String response = SIM900.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println("Response: " + response);
        SIM900.flush();
        SIM900.print(response);
      }
    }
    
    void sendCommand(String command) {
      const char STX = '\x02';
      const char ETX = '\x03';
    
      SIM900.print(STX);
      SIM900.print(command);
      SIM900.print(ETX);
      SIM900.println();
    }
```

Here is the error I receive on the PC, python console:

```
Error:
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

     14         time.sleep(1)
     15         response = ser.read_all()
---> 16         response = response.decode('ascii')  # Already tried decode using 'latin1' encoding
     17         print("Response:", response)
     19 except serial.SerialException as e:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The byte character with a value of 254 (0xFE in hexadecimal shown in the error) represents the "þ" character in the Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) character encoding. It is known as "Latin Small Letter Thorn" and is used in some languages, such as Icelandic. I don't know where that character comes from since I don't send any special characters, only what I typed in my code.i.e 'TEST as you go test and test again\r\n' and return that back to the pc.

I am actually trying to use the Arduino to send commands to a TEOM control unit which expects data in the format
[STX][data][ETX]
That part is the send function at the bottom of the code.

Extra bytes cause the communication with the control unit not to work so I am assuming the extra characters are my problem. I tested similar python code to control the unit with a raspberry pi 4 and the RS-232 cable and that works okay, however I need the Arduino Uno to work as well.

What I have tried:

- Using serial.flush() on the arduino before reading and sending the response- no change
- ser.reset_input_buffer() after sending the data in the python code- no change
- Changing the encoding in python to latin-1 or utf-8, gives worse results, even the actual data sometimes gets shown as unprintable characters.
- Printing the byte values with their characters and comparing them, the extra characters appear at the beginning of the response from the arduino.

What I find strange is that the number of unwanted characters (254 ) is the same as the number of spaces. A single word such as just 'Test' gives no extra characters. However,the command to the control unit will have spaces and I can't change that.

For example for the input:

```
Input with 7 spaces: 'TEST as you go test and test again\r\n
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
...[expected response continues here]

Input with 4 spaces: 'TEST as you go again\r\n'
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
Byte: 254
...[expected response continues here]
```

Python version: 3.9.12
Arduino IDE:

> Version: 2.0.3 Date: 2022-12-05T09:30:25.331Z CLI Version: 0.29.0
> [76251df9]

Why are there extra characters in the communication?
How can I fix this?
Please help.

**Edit add response with empty decode():**

When decode()/encode() is left empty without specifying the encoding this error is received on this line: response = response.decode()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Adding a print statement to print the byte values before the decode eg:

```py
response = ser.read_all()
print(response)
response = response.decode()
```

Gives something like this

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffTEST as you go test and test again\r\r\n'
```

I am unsure where the extra characters \xff comes from, but my guess is that it occurs when the serial reads characters before an actual response is received, because hex value \xff means all the bits are set to the maximum value since the maximum hex character is 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

try encoding and decoding with encode(encoding='utf8') or leave the parenthesis empty : decode()/encode(). (because utf8 is the default parameter)
nowadays most of the time we dont use ascii we use utf. and i guess that's how the arduino is encoding the text.

Comment: Leaving the parentheses empty did not work. Actually that was the default mode before I tried ascii